# CascadeType.Merge in entity relations with Spring Data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities (`Consultancy` - the owner, and `InterviewType`) with `@ManyToMany` bidirectional relations. User can attach the interview type to the Consultancy. I know that in a case of we're using a Hibernate we can just invoke `merge()` method on `EntityManager` to persist a new transient entity or update a detach object, but what about `save()` method in Spring Data or Spring Data have another method? Does it make some effect on a depend entity of a `@ManyToMany` relations? In case of 'yes' in what way? Does it invoke a Hibernates `merge()` method under the hood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the implementation from the 2.0.2 version:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

The merge is invoked under the hood if the persistence provider decides that the passed entity new.. does not have an id / is not managed by the persistence provider.. So that 'new' depends a bit on the underlying implementation of the `EntityInformation`.

In general it should invoke the merge when there is a need though i had situations where I had to write my own custom merge logic as the implicit `merge` was not ivoked